# find closest div element, logical part. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, logic

I am trying to find closest (to current pageYOffset) div element, but i have a problem with logic.
Can you help me to wright working algorithm?

My code is:

```
var closestDiv = window.pageYOffset - arrayOfSceneDivs[0].offsetTop;
var closestDivIndex = 0;
for (var a = 0; a < arrayOfSceneDivs.length; a++) {
    if (((window.pageYOffset - arrayOfSceneDivs[a].offsetTop) - closestDiv) < 10 ) {
        closestDiv = window.pageYOffset - arrayOfSceneDivs[a].offsetTop;
        closestDivIndex = a;
    }
}
if (closestDivIndex != 0) {
    i = closestDivIndex;
    console.log(arrayOfSceneDivs);
    console.log(i);
    window.scrollTo(0, arrayOfSceneDivs[i].offsetTop);
}
```

Comment: And by closest, you mean visually on the screen, not in the DOM.

Comment: @adeneo Sure, Closest to current window.pageYOffset

Comment: Distance used here is always a positive real number, use `Math.abs()` when calculating distances.